# Restore missing grub2 files and edit grub to boot windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: grub2, menu

Please this is not a duplicate of anything as I have tried most other things and still can't figure this out.

grub Windows 10 menu entry is wrong and boots to windows recovery instead of going to windows desktop.

Laptop: ASUS ROG G551VW with UEFI GPT partitioning and factory installed windows 10 64bit. XUbuntu 16.04 installed secondary on sda5.

I need help editing grub and correct the windows 10 grub entry.

Currently Windows 10 is booted from Bios boot manager, not grub.
XUbuntu 16.04 boots just fine.

If there is a way to create new `/etc/default/grub` which will have all important information needed?

[image: grub windows 10 not working entry]

[image: Current partition table]

OBS!: Please don't refer to boot-repair as it does not work with 16.xx. When running it, it will give you commands to paste into terminal and these commands are deprecated so they will fail, then boot-repair can't continue and you can only chose discard which will remove grub totally from the system and delete most files needed to repair or re-install grub - it's a nightmare I had to deal with yesterday - trying to manually re-install grub running from live media fails because boot-repair removed the needed files including grub-install, grub-common, grub-pc, `/etc/default/grub /boot/grub/grub.cfg`, `40_custom` and so on. Supergrub2 disc saved me and re-installed grub but only partially - `/etc/default/grub` `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, `40_custom` is still missing. So I got `/etc/default/grub` `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` from my own pc and it seem to be the same. Point being, don't use boot-repair with 16.xx.

EDIT: As stated already this is not a duplicate, windows were pre-installed from factory and Xubuntu installed secondary - so please read before making sugesstions! Also boot-repair removed vital grub files and programs(explained in comment further down), so various commands no longer works - neither do grub customizer. So what I need is to get those files and progs re-installed without breaking the system further, as I now have grub back with grub.cfg  and /etc/default/grub - but still wrong win10 entry and missing grub-install, grub-common, grub-pc, grub-update, 40_custom

I have a sample win10 entry, just need to know which file to add it - and then I will modify it to fit this laptop with uuid and gpt.

The laptop is not mine, it belong to a friend who need it for work in newspaper office so I can't always get to it. As stated before, windows 10 boots from bios option and this works until a grub solution has been found. Xubuntu boot just fine from grub.

Comment: you have to tell us exactly what you have tried and exactly how it failed, otherwise, how will we know not to suggest those conventional fixes again?

Comment: Actually I did tell you exactly what I like to do: Edit grub to get windows 10 to boot from grub and not going to recovery + create new /etc/default/grub which will have all important information needed. If i start with all i have tried then this is going to be a very long thread. Right now Windows can boot from bios boot manager and ubuntu from grub. links to screenshot of non working grub entry has been suplied.

Comment: Zanna, I'm sorry to say this but you seem to be an endless record! I told you already what I like to do, please stop asking what what I did as that is not relevant.

Comment: Well, you need to tell us everything you've tried here on the site, otherwise some idiot is going to press the **Close this as a duplicate** button because there is an absolute lack of evidence that it's not a duplicate!

Comment: Why do you have Debian's GRUB? Or is that not your photo?

Answer (score 1):

According to your description. I can​ give you a suggestion to install [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) bootloader. I also had a similar incident when my GRUB crashed but boot-repair did the job. Please visit the attached link.Hope this works with you

Comment: Did you use ubuntu 16.04 with boot-repair? If not then that answer is not relevant - boot-repair does not work on 16.04! Im sorry to be harsh, but i have read through about 50+ answers on how to edit grub2 to include Windows 10 and none of them worked for me. I'm not interested in installing another bootloader, only in getting grub2 working!

Comment: Yes 16.04.2 with boot-repair and it restored grub properly

Comment: One more thing there is a sub-menu in GRUB named Advanced options for ubuntu. Check whether Windows boot manager is present here. If so then you can edit the menu using GRUB customizer

Comment: So when using boot-repair and you paste the lines into terminal to purge grub and install grub again - didn't you get a message about --force-yes were depreceated and to use --allow- option instead? Except the only --allow- option I seem to be able to find is --allow-unauthenticated which is not working for this. This is why i say boot-repair is not working with 16.04

Comment: GRUB customizer is not working because of missing /etc/default/grub and 40_custom and DEVICE MAP FILE and grub-install - that boot-repair removed - it comes up with an error saying to contact developer of GRUB customizer.

Comment: Use the recommended repair option in boot- repair. No need to paste anything in terminal. Did you check out the advanced options in grub? Was Windows boot mgr present there? If yes then only use grub customizer.

Comment: +1 for rEFInd and I wish I could add another +1 for testing boot-repair disk on 16.04.  **:-)**

Comment: Pranal> using boot-repair I chose the recommended repair, then it gave some lines to paste in terminal and here I got the errors  about broken and held packages and that --force-yes were depreceated and to use --allow command instead - no explanation to which --allow to use. using --allow-unauthenticated - same error again. Same thing happened when I tried the command without --allow or --force-yes. boot-repair would not complete without these commands being completed in terminal and only option were to chose discard, which removed grub totally from the system including vital files

Comment: As I have explained earlier, grub customizer does not work after boot-repair screwed up the system, there are missing config files and programs needed for grub customizer to work and if I continue anyway I get an error telling me to contact the author of grub customizer, so please forget boot-repair and grub customizer for now and focus on the problem at hand, how to manually repair the damage and edit grub to include the correct Win10 entry and not one that boots to windows recovery? I now have a sample win10 entry that can be used, just need to know where to put it and how?

Comment: grub customizer indicating missing files
https://www.dropbox.com/s/p0hiheko4uwc39b/IMG_20170408_213421.jpg?dl=0    _ how to restore those files?

Comment: I got a working grub.cfg(still wrong win10 entry though) now thanks to Supergrub disk, and a /etc/default/grub copied from my pc to the damaged one - but the rest is still missing: grub-install, grub-common, grub-pc, grub-update, grub-efi, 40_custom

Comment: In case you have totally removed grub then you can do a fresh install of grub in your hard disk. Please refer the ubuntu help pages help.ubuntu.com for more details regarding this.

Comment: If you are still not able to work around with grub and you don't want to install any other bootloader to hard disk then I suggest installing rEFInd to an EFI partition on a flash drive. While booting you just need to plug the drive and you'll be able to select rhe OS from the boot menu. Once booted you can remove the flash drive